# How to use Tweepy set_access_token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, twitter-oauth

So I am a complete beginner to Tweepy, and I was trying to get started from their [tutorial](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/getting_started.html) with the following code:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

Before the `OAuthHandler`, I added the `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, etc as something like:

```
consumer_key = 'aslkjfdalskdjflsjlfsakdjflasjdkf' 
consumer_secret = 'ldsjlfksajldjflasjdljflasjdf'

access_token = 'asldkfjasjdfalsjdflksajkfdlasd'
acess_token_secret = 'alskjdflksajdlfjsalfd'
```

Of course, with the proper values. however, when I run the whole example, I get nothing printed out. What am I doing wrong? I understand I am supposed to get a list of tweets back. Am I not supposed to pass the values in as a string? I tried looking for tweepy documentation regarding `OAuthHandler` but didn't really come up with anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might have this problem, it was a very simple issue– I created a new account and didn't have anything in my timeline. Naturally, nothing was printing.